# Weird browser-looking application opens itself in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: browser, malware, remote-login

Today, a weird aplication, that looks like a default Ubuntu browser (not firefox) opens at random times (it opened two times today) and that never happened before to me. I taked a screenshot and i'm scanning my whole system with ClamAv.

[image]

(The window's name is in Spanish, it kind of says: remote point login)

Anyone knows what is that and why it appears? Could it be malware?

I'll update when the ClamAv scan finishes...

Comment: No, it's not malware ... It's the network-manager checking connectivity ... It's normal and safe.

Comment: @Raffa Thanks for asking so quickly! I guess it does answer it but I still don't know why it is appearing now, I have been using Ubuntu for almost 2 years now, thats why it seems weird to me... Anyways I see now it's nothing to worry about, thank you again!